# How to search over multiple fields using sequelize in node js?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am developing a simple blog which includes users and posts. Users and Posts have different fields. I want to search for a keyword using one function. To achieve it, I should be able to search using sequelize from multiple columns. For more information,  I provide the contents of models as a dictionary below.

```
Users = {
    'firstName': Sequelize.STRING,
    'email': Sequelize.STRING,
    'password': Sequelize.STRING,
}
```

```
Posts = {
    'title': Sequelize.STRING,
    'content': Sequelize.TEXT,
}
```

**What I want to achieve:**

```
model.findAll({
    where: {
        *: {
        [Op.iLike]: "%searchingkeyword%"
        }
})
// Imagine model is passed to function and it can either be Users or Posts
```

**: means all fields*

Question: How to search over multiple fields withouth specifically writing them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer which I do not really know if it is ok solution. (I am coming from Python background!)

*Dependencies*:

[lodash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash) - I used to filter out some keys
[sequelize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize) - I have used Op from sequelize

```
const _ = require("lodash");
const { Op } = require("sequelize");

...

const value = {
    [Op.iLike]: "%" + req.query.search + "%"
}

...
const fields = Object.keys(
    _.omit(model.rawAttributes, [
        "password",
        "id",
        "createdAt",
        "updatedAt",
    ])
);
const filters = {};
fields.forEach((item) => (filters[item] = value));

const result = await model.findAndCountAll({
    where: {
         [Op.or]: filters
    }
});
...
```

Comment: That is a very clever solution

Comment: What is I wanted to match say exact `id`, AND where any filter matches any field?